# How to get the minimum value greater than zero?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the lowest value greater than zero, and after many tries searching for solutions here, I am still not able to get what I want.

I've tried to add $filtered_array, didnt work.

added some extra arrays, still not working.

```
  $sum3 = 0;
  $temp3 = $limit;
  $tmp_date3  = new DateTime($curdate);
  $tmp_date3 ->modify('+1 day');
  $tmp_next3 = $tmp_date3->format('Y-m-d');

  $min3 = $price3[trim($tmp_next3)];
  $max3 = $price3[trim($tmp_next3)];
      while($temp3 != 0 ){
        $sum3 += $price3[$tmp_next3];
        $min3 = min($min3, $price3[$tmp_next3]);
        $max3 = max($max3, $price3[$tmp_next3]);
        $date  = new DateTime($tmp_next3);
        $date ->modify('+1 day');
        $tmp_next3 = $date ->format('Y-m-d');
        $temp3--;
    }
 $average3 = $sum3/$limit;
 $cheaper3 = $min3+$average3/10;
 $normal3 = $max3-$average3/10;
```

the $min3 should be a value greater than zero/blank, otherwise, it affects all the calculation afterward. What do you suggest?

```
$price3 = array(59, 55, 46, 68, 0, 25, 10, 0)
```

Since I am a very beginner on development, I would appreciate if you could hep me with my code directly.

Comment: What is $price3 array in your code?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre], including sample data and expected output.

Comment: I just added some extra info in the description

Comment: _“Since I am a very beginner on development, I would appreciate if you could hep me with my code directly.”_ - please don’t expect people to _fully_ write the code for you, that’s not what the purpose of this site is. (Plus you’d probably _stay_ at the beginner level, if we did that.) You still need to make an effort. I suggested a basic solution to get the minimum value > 0 from an array of values in my answer - please see how you can adapt that for your data. (Your “example” in the screenshot does not show the _actual_ data structure either, but some kind of formatted debug output.)

Comment: Alright, got it. First question here on stackoverflow. Learning by doing, right? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic example, showing how easily something like this can be done:

```
$data = [17, 4, -5, 2, 99, -77];

$min = PHP_INT_MAX;

foreach($data as $value) {
  if($value > 0 && $value < $min) {
    $min = $value;
  }
}

echo "Minimum value that is greater zero: ", $min;
```

Output:

> Minimum value that is greater zero: 2

Please adapt it to whatever your actual data structure is yourself.